# call ajax response on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having two page gallery.php and post-result.php..I am getting my ajax response in the div(modal-content)which is on gallery.php on the same page i want to store the div value in a php variable .

```
<div class="modal-content"> </div>
```

my ajax code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".varr").click(function(){
var dataId = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
jQuery.ajax({url:"post-result.php?dataId="+dataId,cache:false,
 success:function(result){
jQuery(".modal-content").html(result);}

});


});  });
```

Comment: why are you changing question after answer?  The solution of your question is you have to just change `jQuery(".modal-content").html(result);` to `jQuery("#modal-content").html(result);`

Comment: sorry for that.....it was just my typing mistake.....i have written id instead of class

Comment: and my question is that how to get the  div value in php variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not set data in php variable from ajax call

Comment: is there any other way..?

Comment: basically you cant do it using the javascript or jquery.
u are using the jquery to set data in your "model-content"
so make use of the same

jQuery("#modal-content").html();

Comment: you cant set the data from javascript/jquery

javascript/jquery client side scripting
PHP server scripting

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
jQuery(".modal-content").html(result);
```

to

```
jQuery("#modal-content").html(result);
```

Comment: by using id instead of class....can i store the div value in php variable??

Comment: you can able to use either id or class but you used id in div and trying to set content using class. @varsha

Comment: oh yeah ...it was just typing mistake....i am getting my ajax response in a modal-content div ....